# Vue - FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

how can solve this problem?

I'd tried to many methods, but it's still cannot solve this problem.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1724:03F00758]       47 ms: Mark-sweep 1.0 (3.3) -> 0.9 (3.3) MB, 0.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.555, current mu = 0.266) allocation failure GC in old space requested
[1724:03F00758]       48 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 0.9 (3.3) -> 0.9 (3.3) MB, 0.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.449, current mu = 0.260) last resort GC in old space requested
[1724:03F00758]       49 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 0.9 (2.3) -> 0.9 (3.3) MB, 1.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.285, current mu = 0.042) last resort GC in old space requested


FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! vuestic-admin@1.9.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vuestic-admin@1.9.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

or used this methods

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0

IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%.
  node  "--max-old-space-size=4096 %~dp0\..\webpack\bin\webpack.js" %*
)
```

it's still cannot working.

I'd tried to used node --max-old-space-size=4096, npm install -g increase-memory-limit. But all cannot build the product.

this is my script

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve:book": "vue-cli-service serve --mode book",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "inspect": "vue-cli-service inspect > inspect.js",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
```

Comment: If 4GB are not sufficient to build your app - you should seriously think about getting rid of some of its dependencies ...

Comment: @IVOGELOV such as?

Comment: One of those that is listed under `dependencies` key in your `package.json` file.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I has solved this problem. The reason is node.js different version.